# How can I rearrange loaded time series data?

Tags: r, data-structures, load, reshape

What I've got is data in a txt file (mydata.txt) something like this:

```
Variable, DateTime, Value, Quality
A, 01-01-1970 00:00:00, 0, 0
A, 01-01-1970 00:02:00, 2, 2
A, 01-01-1970 00:04:00, 4, 1
A, 01-01-1970 00:06:00, 6, 0
B, 01-01-1970 00:02:00, 0.2, 0
B, 01-01-1970 00:04:00, 0.4, 1
B, 01-01-1970 00:06:00, 0.6, 1
B, 01-01-1970 00:10:00, 1.0, 0
C, 01-01-1970 00:00:00, 20.0, 0
C, 01-01-1970 00:04:00, 16.0, 0
C, 01-01-1970 00:08:00, 12.0, 3
```

And I can load it into R without problems with

```
read.csv("mydata.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

or

```
read.table("mydata.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

But **what I'd like** to work with in r would be something like this:

```
DateTime, A_Value, A_Quality, B_Value, B_Quality, C_Value, C_Quality
01-01-1970 00:00:00, 0, 0, NA, NA, 20.0, 0
01-01-1970 00:02:00, 2, 2, 0.2, 0, NA, NA
01-01-1970 00:04:00, 4, 1, 0.4, 1, 16.0, 0
01-01-1970 00:06:00, 6, 0, 0.6, 1, NA, NA
01-01-1970 00:08:00, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12.0, 3
01-01-1970 00:10:00, NA, NA, 1.0, 0, NA, NA
```

(where the first column is a date/time type).

I don't know which or how many different variables there are in my file (i.e. A, B, ... Z) and I don't know their names - all I know is their column.

**How do I** get from the data set I have in the text file to to the data set I'd like to work with in R?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read your data in as normal:

```
mydata <- read.table("mydata.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Then "reshape" it from what is called a "long" format to a "wide" format using one of *several* methods.

This is just 1 line in base R using `reshape`:

```
reshape(mydata, direction = "wide", idvar = "DateTime", timevar = "Variable")
#                DateTime Value.A Quality.A Value.B Quality.B Value.C Quality.C
# 1   01-01-1970 00:00:00       0         0      NA        NA      20         0
# 2   01-01-1970 00:02:00       2         2     0.2         0      NA        NA
# 3   01-01-1970 00:04:00       4         1     0.4         1      16         0
# 4   01-01-1970 00:06:00       6         0     0.6         1      NA        NA
# 8   01-01-1970 00:10:00      NA        NA     1.0         0      NA        NA
# 11  01-01-1970 00:08:00      NA        NA      NA        NA      12         3
```

Comment: Thanks! Works well too. Can see I'll need to sort by DateTime. What's with the record numbers going from 4 to 8 and from 8 to 11 when I do it like this?

Comment: @MortenGrum, yes. Unlike the approach from "reshape2", `reshape` doesn't make any assumptions that you want to sort your data at the same time, but returns the data according to the idvariables in the order they were encountered. A simple `mydf[order(mydf$DateTime), ]` will take care of that for you. Similarly, the row names (record numbers) correlate to the first row in which the function encountered that "idvar" in the source data. You'll notice that the first time of "00:10:00" is in the 8th row of your sample data, hence that's the row name you see here.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the `reshape2` package:

First step: `melt` your `data.frame`

```
require(reshape2)
df.m <- melt(df, id.var = 1:2) # changed names(df)[1:2] to 1:2 (following @Anandamahto's comment)
```

Second step: `cast` to the result:

```
dcast(df.m, DateTime ~ Variable + variable, fill=NA)

#               DateTime A_Value A_Quality B_Value B_Quality C_Value C_Quality
# 1  01-01-1970 00:00:00       0         0      NA        NA      20         0
# 2  01-01-1970 00:02:00       2         2     0.2         0      NA        NA
# 3  01-01-1970 00:04:00       4         1     0.4         1      16         0
# 4  01-01-1970 00:06:00       6         0     0.6         1      NA        NA
# 5  01-01-1970 00:08:00      NA        NA      NA        NA      12         3
# 6  01-01-1970 00:10:00      NA        NA     1.0         0      NA        NA
```

Comment: @Arun, any reason you use `idvar = names(df)[1:2]`? I think that `idvar = 1:2` is sufficient. +1, of course.

Comment: @Ananda, no, not really. I usually don't say `idvar` at all. I use `melt(df, names(df)[1:2])`. I'll modify it. I have never used the indices directly. Thanks for noting!!

Comment: @Arun, I actually prefer to just enter a vector of names, just in case I decide to change the order of my columns or in case another function changes the order of my columns. I know it's a rare occurrence, but I prefer to be explicit whenever possible.